# What signal is being sent to an EC2 Instance on shut down?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, linux-kernel

When you terminate an instance-store pv instance through the AWS console or the API, what "signal" does it receive so it knows it has to gracefully shut down?

First guess would be ACPI, but on boot Linux reports

```
ACPI in unprivileged domain disabled
ACPI: Interpreter disabled.
```

Comment: ACPI I'd imagine...just like other virtualization software.

Comment: On boot Linux says ACPI is disabled. So probably not.

Comment: Why would it be different from default physical hardware signalling? I tend to think it is -15 (TERM), and -9 (KILL), as it always were.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EC2 uses Xen. The Xen PV driver handles the shutdown. If you were using an HVM instance, ACPI would handle the shutdown.

Comment: Which PV Driver is that (kernel config option)?

Comment: CONFIG_XEN is the config option. In the source code see arch/x86/xen/enlighten.c.

Comment: Ok, but how does user-space become aware of that then? I take it acpid won't see these events.

Comment: When a domU boots it registers a watch for "control/shutdown" key in the XenStore with the callback function "shutdown_handler()." In that function orderly_poweroff() is called which in turn calls  call_usermodehelper_exec() which executes the command in the variable "poweroff_cmd" which is...wait for it.../sbin/poweroff. This rabbit hole starts here: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/drivers/xen/manage.c#L229

Comment: I can't upvote this enough. Thank you so much Mark! I would never have found this without your help!

Answer (score 2):

The command that will be run can be seen by running:

`sysctl kernel.poweroff_cmd`

And can be changed by running (as root):

`sysctl kernel.poweroff_cmd="/usr/bin/systemctl poweroff"`

Which can be made permanent on a modern systemd based system by:

`cat << EOF > /etc/sysctl.d/poweroff.conf
kernel.poweroff_cmd = "/usr/bin/systemctl poweroff"
EOF`

@Mark Wagner explained it, but the `sysctl` aspect wasn't clear to me!