# AWS instance Stop and Terminate don't execute systemd stop script

Tags: amazon-web-services, systemd, ubuntu-18.04

I have a shutdown script that executes just fine after cli `reboot` or `shutdown`, but never executes when an instance is stopped or terminated from aws console.

```
[Unit]
Description=Gracefully shut down remnode to avoid database dirty flag
DefaultDependencies=no
After=poweroff.target shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target kexec.target
RequiresMountsFor=/data
Requires=network-online.target network.target data.mount

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStop=/root/node_shutdown.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes
KillMode=none

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Here is the `journalctl` log for my service. The first two entries are `reboot` via cli, the last 3 entries are 2 instance stops from AWS console. As you can see, there's not even a mention of winding down my service during instance stop. Rebooting from cli however outputs my echo and system logs startup as well as shutdown of the service.

```
-- Logs begin at Sun 2019-10-13 13:02:54 UTC, end at Mon 2019-10-14 19:41:01 UTC. --
Oct 13 13:03:24 ip-10-0-1-182 systemd[1]: Started Gracefully shut down remnode to avoid database dirty flag.
Oct 14 19:27:23 ip-10-0-1-182 systemd[1]: Stopping Gracefully shut down remnode to avoid database dirty flag...
Oct 14 19:27:23 ip-10-0-1-182 node_shutdown.sh[10635]: RUNNING SHUTDOWN SCRIPT
Oct 14 19:27:23 ip-10-0-1-182 systemd[1]: Stopped Gracefully shut down remnode to avoid database dirty flag.
-- Reboot --
Oct 14 19:27:37 ip-10-0-1-182 systemd[1]: Started Gracefully shut down remnode to avoid database dirty flag.
Oct 14 19:28:17 ip-10-0-1-182 systemd[1]: Stopping Gracefully shut down remnode to avoid database dirty flag...
Oct 14 19:28:17 ip-10-0-1-182 node_shutdown.sh[1712]: RUNNING SHUTDOWN SCRIPT
Oct 14 19:28:18 ip-10-0-1-182 systemd[1]: Stopped Gracefully shut down remnode to avoid database dirty flag.
-- Reboot --
Oct 14 19:28:32 ip-10-0-1-182 systemd[1]: Started Gracefully shut down remnode to avoid database dirty flag.
-- Reboot --
Oct 14 19:34:05 ip-10-0-1-182 systemd[1]: Started Gracefully shut down remnode to avoid database dirty flag.
-- Reboot --
Oct 14 19:40:26 ip-10-0-1-182 systemd[1]: Started Gracefully shut down remnode to avoid database dirty flag.
```

**EDIT 2:**

Because it seems like `shutdown` trigger is basically never pulled, I've also tried setting kernel `sysctl kernel.poweroff_cmd` to `/bin/systemctl poweroff` [following this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/584970/what-signal-is-being-sent-to-an-ec2-instance-on-shut-down). Hoping it would trigger the even, but no luck.

Comment: have you tried to put `RemainAfterExit` before `ExecStop`? also can you confirm it is executing during script execution or even not calling at all?

Comment: @asktyagi I have tried various orders, they don't seem to have any impact. Also, I added logs to my post. As you can see, it doesn't even seem to log shutdown of my process.

Comment: I'll update my post when I have more information, but after reaching out to AWS support, the answer seems to be that their primary, canonical Ubuntu 18.04 AMI is the reason for this bug. Using a different AMI, like .NET edition, fixes the issue.

Comment: If You are relying on systemd-logind to initiate shutdown/poweroff on power button press as usual, there can be applications that acquire some inhibtor-lock on shutdown/poweroff event handling of systemd which may cause systemd to ignore or delay this events, leading to EC2 instance externally powered off after timeout of 4 minutes.

Comment: You could try ewith wetting `PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=yes` in /etc/logind.conf and restart systemd-logind to ensure that no application can inhibit systemd-logind from powering off after power button press using inhibitor.

Comment: @SergChernata did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but might be worth exploring:

Have you tried using `Before=` with `ExecStart=` instead of `After=` with `ExecStop=`? i.e. start the node_shutdown.sh script before the final state of a shutdown/halt/reboot is reached. There are answers to similar questions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39604) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522397) that allude to this.

That said, the accepted answer for the first linked question uses neither option! And why it works on a manual shutdown but not a console shutdown I'm not sure. I know a console shutdown registers as a "power button pressed" event - maybe this event is treated differently by the OS?

A power button press triggers an ACPI event which (I think) runs `/etc/acpi/events/hibinit-power` => `/etc/acpi/actions/hibinit-power.sh`, which itself sends a poweroff command to the message bus. It might be worth checking the contents of that .sh in case there's anything funky in there. My vanilla Ubuntu 18.04 looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# shut down system in a way that respects inhibitors
# see: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/9356
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.PowerOff boolean:false
```

As asktyagi suggests it's probably worth determining if the script is actually running - maybe try writing to a log at the top of the node_shutdown script?

Edit - here are the contents of the following files:

**/etc/acpi/events/hibinit-power**

```
event=button/power
action=/etc/acpi/actions/hibinit-power.sh "%e"
```

**/etc/acpi/events/hibinit-sleep**

```
# ACPID config to power down machine if powerbutton is pressed, but only if
# no gnome-power-manager is running

event=button/sleep.*
action=/etc/acpi/actions/sleep.sh %e
```

**/etc/acpi/actions/sleep.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

#PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

do_hibernate() {
    if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
        systemctl hibernate
    else
        pm-hibernate
        swapoff /swap-hibinit
    fi
}


case "$2" in
    SBTN)
        swapon /swap-hibinit && do_hibernate
        ;;
    *)
        logger "ACPI action undefined: $2" ;;
esac
```

One thing to also check is `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to see how the system handles the power key being pressed. Mine appears to have all the defaults set, notably the ones below:

```
[Login]
...
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
...
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
```

I double checked this with a fresh Ubuntu instance built from the AWS stock image (ami-02df9ea15c1778c9c in EU-West-1)

Comment: I did try using `Before` configuration, unfortunately. And I am writing to log, see the last portion of my question. The second part of your answer is interesting. I'm also using Ubuntu 18.04 but my files are different from yours. I have `hibinit-sleep` instead of `hibinit-power`.

Comment: Can you include your contents of `/etc/acpi/events/hibinit-power` ?

Comment: Just edited my answer :)

Comment: But You should note the acpi scripts are only used from acpid service, not for systemd. So it needs to be started to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 AMI. I read the above article and tried updating packages.

```
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt upgrade
```

I don't know why, but it works fine now even when EC2 instance is shutdown via web console. And there are new acpi related scripts that were missing(`hibinit-power`, `hibinit-power.sh`). Would you like to try it out?